# Fill a column with input?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to fill a column with an input text but it doesn't fill in.

How could I do this ?

```
<div class="col-md-6">        
        @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formLogin" })){
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="panel panel-red">
            <div class="panel-heading bg-red">Acesso</div>

                <div class="alert-success" id="errorMessage" style="display:none;margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;"></div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <!--Form-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Email <img src="~/Imagens/required.png" height="6" width="6"></label>
                        <div class="cols-sm-12">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.email, new { Class = "form-control input-lg", placeholder = "Informe o email", maxlength = 255 })
                            </div>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Senha <img src="~/Imagens/required.png" height="6" width="6"></label>
                        <div class="cols-sm-12">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                @Html.PasswordFor(model => Model.password, new { Class = "form-control input-lg", placeholder = "Informe a senha", maxlength = 8 })
                            </div>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">                        
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.keepLogin) 
                        <label for="keepLogin" class="control-label">Me mantenha conectado</label>  
                    </div> 

                </div>                   
            <div class="panel-footer">                
                <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">Acessar</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        }
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: I assume this is an ASP.Net MVC application and that this page is displayed via a get method from the controller. In the controller, are you assigning the the data you wish to appear to the appropriate properties of the model which you are passing to the view?

Comment: Yeah! It is. Then, I just need to change the size of input to fill the rest of area inside de panel using Bootstrap. I thought to use `style=min-width:100%" but I think it will lost the responsiveness.

Comment: I resolved the problem using exactly `style=min-width:100%` and it works very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Visual Studio default Bootstrap template, there is a file named \Content\Site.css

This file overrides Bootstraps behavior for input, select and textarea control and sets the max-width: 280px

Commenting this out should make your controls use the full space.

The following video should help [Twitter Bootstrap & ASP.NET MVC -- Intro / Quickstart with Ben Cull](https://youtu.be/bIGiUSMBwoo?t=642)